# Errors while running audit2allow on ubuntu

Tags: android

installed policycoreutils-python-utils_2.5-2_amd64.deb

```
$ cat logcat | audit2allow
libsepol.context_from_record: user u is not defined
libsepol.context_from_record: could not create context structure
libsepol.context_from_string: could not create context structure
libsepol.sepol_context_to_sid: could not convert u:r:comp_drm:s0 to sid
```

how do I set the context_from_record?